# Having trouble with VBA adding page numbers plus text in Word Header

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, headers, page-numbers, footers

Nothing more humbling than a simple VBA problem that takes all night. I would like to add page numbers to the header of a multi-page document. I have set uo recto/verso pages and no header on primary page. I would something like this
RECTO
|   Title   Volume|
VERSO
| subtitle  Edition   |

I have tried multiple versions of code. This is the closet I've come. Still doesn't work. This is for the recto page.

```
    '''
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1) _
     .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers
      .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleArabic
      .IncludeChapterNumber = False
      .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
      .StartingNumber = 2
      .Add PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, FirstPage:=True
     End With
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
        Selection.InsertAfter Text:=& vbTab & “Title” & vbTab & “Volume”
       End With
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
         Selection.style = ActiveDocument.Styles("_header")
   End With
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
   '''
```

Thank you so much in advance for any pointed. I am lost. Thanks je

Comment: The easiest way to get working code, is by simply using the macro recorder, perform the action manually and see what code it spits out, then mangle that into something you can use.

Comment: If you want the numbering to start on page 2 as 2, you need to set different first page to skip the first page. You need both `Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)` and `Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages)` http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm Use the Range rather than the Selection object.

Comment: Word comes with a built-in Header style. Why are you not using that?

Comment: When I tried to record a macro, it creates a hard path to the page number library when means it will only work on my machine. Unless of course, I'm doing it wrong. Secondly, It's accessing the header, or writing on even  or primary page. It's inserting a page number and then insert text. This is harder that it first started out to be. Thank you for the comments. Good start.

Comment: I do not recommend a recorded macro. You can use it to see some code, but you do not want to be opening headers and using the Selection object but rather writing to the relevant range. There are numerous methods of creating Page Numbers; page numbers in Word are fields. See http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers.

Comment: For instance: `ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.Text = "Hello"` inserts "Hello" into that header instead of the current header. If you define a Range variable and set it to `ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range` and the **collapse** that variable range you can insert the text at the beginning or end of the range.

Comment: More references: See https://bettersolutions.com/word/paragraphs/vba-range-vs-selection.htm, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Range, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Range and Looking at Ranges and Selections https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA.htm.

Comment: You should also look at use of the Alignment Tab to position your information: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Range.InsertAlignmentTab